# How does HashMap determine where to put things?

Tags: java, hashmap

How does the add method in HashMap determine where a key goes in a HashMap? Like, if I was trying to put "S","T","A","C","K" into the HashMap  of size 10, how does it determine where each letter goes?

Comment: Object's `hashCode()` method

Comment: It hashes it.  I'm pretty sure that if you Google for it you'll find a good Wikipedia article or three on hashtables, et al.

Comment: disagree that the content in the previous question is a satisfactory answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

The least significant bits of the object's hash code are used to select a bucket.  Note there is no such thing as a java.util.HashMap of size 10, the size must be a power of 2 so that the bits can be masked to choose a bucket.  If you pass 10 to the constructor, you will get a HashMap with 16 buckets back.

So, reducing to 8 bits for clarity, if "S" returns hashcode 123 java will do

```
01111011 & 00001111 -> 00001011
```

and put S in bucket 11.

The real Hash Map also applies a secondary hash function that shifts bits rightward to make sure there is data with some entropy in the least significant bits so that things have a good chance of being distributed evenly even if their hashCode function isn't that great.